# SMS to iPhone app - Google Maps

Tags: iphone, google-maps, sms

is there a way to have a Map/GPS app hook into the iPhones SMS reader so that it can parse the message and map to that area?

Specifically I'm thinking of a situation where I'm looking for someone's house and they text me their address. I would (from the SMS) be able to say "Map This" and that would send the text to the GPS app and get directions from where I am to that location.

Obviously there would be some error handling for situations like misspellings, locale names ("Burger King", "Hell"), and city/state guesses, but much of this is already handled by Google Maps.

Mostly I'm wondering how to tie the App to the SMS without having to copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

The public SDK doesn't provide an SMS API, so you cannot hook into the SMS messages.  If you are building a location sharing app, you might consider having your own messaging transport layer using the Push Notification functionality.

Comment: Nice call. I'll look into the messaging transport layer. I bet it won't do straight number to app though. ah well.

Comment: what do you mean by 'straight number to app'?